# Nested JSON parsing flutter

Tags: flutter

Error while parsing JSON flutter

`I/flutter ( 6858): type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<SearchModel>'`

Where am I doing wrong? How could I parse exact file /line-location of error?

```
{
  "total": 24,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "currentPage": 1,
  "perPageRecords": 50,
  "values": [
    {
      "_id": "563e2cce31821525104dfe0c",
      "name": "dard ho dil mein to dawaa kiji",
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "_id": "563e2cce31821525104dfe0b",
      "name": "mulk-e-adam main yaaruun ky Id ho rahi hai",
      "description": "",
      "deleted": false
    }
]
```

Sample Model crearted this way

```
class SearchPagination {
  int total;
  int totalPages;
  String currentPage;
  int perPageRecords;
  List<SearchModel> values;

  SearchPagination({this.total, this.totalPages, this.currentPage, this.perPageRecords, this.values});

  factory SearchPagination.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SearchPagination(
      total: json["total"] as int,
      totalPages: json["totalPages"] as int,
      currentPage: json["currentPage"] as int,
      perPageRecords: json["perPageRecords"] as int,
      values: json["values"].map((a) => SearchModel.fromJson(a)),
    );
  }
}

class SearchModel {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final bool deleted;

  SearchModel({this.id, this.name, this.description, this.deleted});

  factory SearchModel.fromJson(Map<SearchModel, dynamic> json) {
    return SearchModel(id: json["id"], name: json["name"], description: json["description"] as String, deleted: json["deleted"]);
  }
}
```

This way service is being called

```
  Future<SearchPagination> fetchSearches({int page: 1}) async {
    var url = Uri.https(baseFinalUrl, 'additional/searches', {'page': page.toString()});
    return _getJson(url).then((json) {
      print(json);

      return SearchPagination.fromJson(json);
    });
  }
```

What is exact error while parsing JSON? Is there any line to line debugger for a flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
      values: json["values"].map((a) => SearchModel.fromJson(a)),
```

with

```
      values: (json["values"] as List).map((a) => SearchModel.fromJson(a)).toList(),
```

Because the result of `map` isn't a list, it has to be converted to `List`.

Comment: this ended with `I/flutter ( 7144): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<SearchModel, dynamic>'`

Comment: Why is SearchModel.fromJson taking `Map<SearchModel, dynamic>` as argument, shouldn't it be `SearchModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)`?

Comment: Corrected, Fixed. Thanks

Comment: BTW, Its better to use `json_serializable` and `json_annotation` packages, to auto generate these methods. Worth a look

Answer (score 3):

create your dart class by visiting [here](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

paste your json data over there it will output the required class file

use that class file to fetch your json data